# Autoload classes with Zend based naming convention or no convention at all with Symfony 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony

How can I use the Symfony2 ClassLoader to autoload classes that dont follow PEAR naming conventions and don't use namespaces?

It seems from the symfony2 docs that this isn't possible.  How does one include API helper libraries or other files that don't follow these types of conventions (i.e. they instead follow Zend conventions or no naming conventions at all)?

Comment: Are you talking about Zend 1 or Zend 2?  I have not used Zend 2 but Zend 1 does follow PEAR and can easily be loaded using the UniversalLoader.  Just need to set an include path as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register autoloading functions for those classes using [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.spl-autoload-register.php). This will let you have several autoloaders rune one after another, until one manages to load requied class.

Answer (score 1):

Code example of what Mchl said

in app/autoload.php

```
...
$loader->register();
...
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Own autoloader for non-namespaced nor PEAR lib. Replace tcpdf with yours.
function myLoader()
{
    $file = __DIR__ . '/../vendor/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
    if (!file_exists($file))
    {
        return false;
    }
    require_once $file;
}

spl_autoload_register('myLoader');
```