# In Symfony2 where do I put e.g. TCPDF?

Tags: php, symfony, tcpdf

I'm on Symfony 2.0 and understood that third-party libraries go in /vendor. I have two third party classes I'm using, one is TCPDF and another is a Paypal class. Neither have formal Symfony2 Bundles.

So I followed the instructions here which namespaces them and makes them usable inside /vendor:

[Add third party libraries to Symfony 2](http://www.kiwwito.com/article/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2)

This works and I can access them from my Controllers. However I'm  rethinking if that's the right thing. Whenever I do..

```
php bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

..those custom classes disappear because they don't have a Git repo in 'deps'. This has caused real problems e.g. when trying to deploy on e.g. PagodaBox. I get the strong instinct that this code while 'third-party' belongs closer to the code of my app.

If that's true, should it:

- Sit next to my Controllers in src/MyCompany/MyBundle/Controller/tcpdf.php
- Be with my other custom-written services in src/MyCompany/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/tcpdf.php
- Go in its own directory under my bundle: src/MyCompany/MyBundle/TCPDF/tcpdf.php

If I move these two classes from /vendor to one of the above, would I access it from a Controller with a 'use' statement, or would I need to define it in 'services.yml'?

I hope this isn't so much a matter of discussion or opinion but some guidance I've missed or best practise I'm unaware of that a more experienced Symfony2 dev would know.

Would it be sensible to switch to Composer even before Symfony 2.1 is ready?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using open source bundles such as this TCPDF bundle: https://github.com/ioalessio/IoTcpdfBundle and this payments bundle: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSPaymentPaypalBundle

Comment: IoTcpdf seems mainly a Tcpdf bridge to output Twig templates as PDFs: not something I need. It doesn't include Tcpdf within itself, it says put Tcpdf manually in your vendor dir, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Matt's suggestion is more directly relevant. I looked at JMSPayment today and while I'd love to use it someday, it has a lot of dependencies and the documentation doesn't provide details on how to use it as a straightforward interface to the Paypal API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using deps to manage vendor libraries then you should add the git repo's for those libraries there.

For TCPDF you can use:

```
[TCPDF]
    git=git://tcpdf.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/tcpdf/tcpdf
    target=/tcpdf
```

If you have other libraries that aren't in a public repo then you may want to commit them to your own repo.

The same would hold true for Composer. Just the syntax for adding non-packagist repo's is different.

Comment: Matt: thanks for the answer. 

How did you get that Git repo for TCPDF. Did you construct the URL yourself from http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Git ? Is it going to be better to use that than https://github.com/tcpdf/tcpdf ? The other library (Paypal, closed-source for which I bought a license) I've made edits on, so I think I'll include in my own source tree as a service (in DependencyInjection) unless you think otherwise.

Comment: The SourceForge one is where the project is developed. The GitHub one is just a mirror. Either would be fine to use.

Comment: Just to complete Matt's answer, once you've included TCPDF in your deps and updated vendors, the next step is: IN     app/autoload.php     ADD    'TCPDF' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/tcpdf',   TO     $loader->registerPrefixes(array());    You can then use it in a Controller or Service e.g. $pdf = new \TCPDF();

Comment: ..which worked for me on local but not when using Capifony with symlinked directories on the live server. For what solved that, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253477/autoload-classes-with-zend-based-naming-convention-or-no-convention-at-all-with/10901809#10901809